# Is it possible to skip over bytes when using Python's struct.unpack?

Tags: python, struct, unpack

It is possible to use Python's [struct.unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to extract the useful values from a [Bitmap file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header), as follows:

```
magic, file_size, _, _, data_offset = struct.unpack('<2sLHHL', file_header)
assert magic == 'BM'
```

Is there any way to avoid the need to assign to `_` (or another throwaway variable) here? Is it possible to change the format string to make `struct.unpack` skip over the two unused `H` fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use the "x" code to skip 1 byte. (see here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)

I.e., replace "H" with "xx" in the format code.

Comment: note that you can use the count prefix to indicate an arbitrary number of bytes, i.e. `4x` would discard the 4 bytes that were previously being captured by `HH`